# How to hide a row the text you have, jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I currently fill a table dynamically in the following way:

```
var formas_pagos = $('.formas_pagos');
                        var input_cantidad ="";
                        var text_forma_pago = "";
                        $.each(response.data, function(index,value){
                            console.log(value.disponible);
                            if (value.disponible === 0){
                                input_cantidad = '<input type="number" step="0.01" name="cantidad" class="cantidad" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" placeholder="Cantidad" disabled="true">';
                            }
                            else{
                                input_cantidad = '<input type="number" step="0.01" name="cantidad" class="cantidad" attr-num-doc="' + value.forma_pago + '" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" placeholder="Cantidad">';
                            }
                            $('<tr>')
                                .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td nombrePago').text(value.forma_pago))
                                .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td cantPago').text(value.disponible.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,')))
                                .append('<div class="cod_forma_pago" style="display:none">' + value.cod_forma_pago + '</div>')
                                .append('<div class="cod_banco" style="display:none">' + value.Cod_Banco + '</div>')
                                .append('<div class="monto_pago" style="display:none">' + value.monto_pago + '</div>')
                                .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td')
                                    .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content')
                                                .append('<input type="checkbox" name="tipo_pago" class="tipo_pago derecha" attr-num-doc="' + value.forma_pago + '" value="' + value.disponible + '"/>')
                                                .append($('<span/>').addClass('item-media').append('<i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>'))))
                                .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell classCantidad derecha')
                                                    .append(input_cantidad))
                                .appendTo(formas_pagos);
                        });
 if (tipo_envio === "2" && $('.nombrePago').text() === "Efectivo"){
                        $('.nombrePago').hide();
                    }
```

but I need to hide the row that it contains in the class .name I pay the text "Effective". Try as follows:

```
if (tipo_envio === "2" && $('.nombrePago').text() === "Efectivo"){
 $('.nombrePago').hide();
}
```

Beforehand thank you very much.

Comment: Please post HTML code too also, what is `tipo_envio`

Comment: But what is the problem your code looks fine is it not hiding that class?, is your console displaying any errors?